# How to list only current user orders if not an admin (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm just now developing my first rails app, so this might be a dumb question to some. I would like to let the current_user see only their own orders if they are not an admin. I was able to set only admins can see all orders, but I'm having a hard time enabling current user to see, list and delete only their own orders. My app has a `:orders` model that `belongs_to :users` and a `:users` model with `has_many :orders`.

This is how my orders_controller.rb look like:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :drop_address)
    end
end
```

My question is how do I allow only the current user to list and see all orders made by them only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is gem named [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for you.
Please read [wiki page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki).
Need more help? let me know :)

define ability

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Order, :user_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

from controller query by accessible_by

```
@orders = Order.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had cancan installed and was a much simpler approach. That actually fixed one section of my problem. I was able to let only the current user see his order, but he can still access someones individually order by direct accessing other users orders like http://..../orders/2 for example. How do I go around to fix that?

Comment: I think you should put magic method from [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions) `load_and_authorize_resource` in your controller.

Comment: @gotva Awesome, that couldn't be easier! Thanks

Comment: @gotva Actually while putting `load_and_authorize_resource` blocked non admin users from accessing orders from others, it also blocked them from creating/editing/deleting their own orders. Any suggestions?

Comment: load_and_authorize_resource method is working against abilities. you can define abilities as you want.

Comment: @xmpolaris Thanks for the help, it was actually an error on my end.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to do it on two levels. In index you have to fetch orders for the current users so users can only see his orders. the second level is you make sure that the user may enter an order url that doesnt belong to him, so check for that in the other actions(edit,update,delete,show).
2. Or you can use declarative authorization gem. it is very helpful https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization

-hint: for naming conventions change belongs_to :users in order model to belongs_to :user (belongs_to is always singular)

**This is how your controller should look like**

```
#this is the filter called before each method to make sure the user is authorized to access the order
before_filter :authorize_user, :only => [:edit,:update,:delete,:show]

def index
  authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
  #here fetch the orders of the current user only
  @orders = current_user.orders
end

#and then goes all your methods here as normal 

private 

def authorize_user
  unless current_user.eql?(@order.user)
    flash[:notice]="You are not authorized to access this order"
    redirect_to orders_path 
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason when I try accessing the http://.../orders/ I get an error for no being an Admin and when I try accessing the http://.../orders/1 I get his error: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass from `def authorize_user unless current_user.eql?(@order.user)`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: try making it, both in one call 
before_action :set_order,:authorize_user, :only => [:edit,:update,:destroy,:show]

Comment: No, that didn't do it unfortunately.

Comment: ok in set_order method put that line after finding the order and see what you get

 -raise @order.inspect